# Place an html file's contents in a specific part of a GitHub pages layout file

Tags: html, github, layout, jekyll, github-pages

I am using Jekyll in GitHub pages and I want to place an entire HTML file's content inside of a Jekyll layout file.

This would be kind of like an Android Studio Activity Fragment (I believe) and will not be useful if you only view the fragment code in a browser.

I am imagining something like `{{ content: fragment.html }}` instead of the current page's content (`{{ content }}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax:

`{% include fragment.html %}`

Don't wrap your `fragment.html` in the `<html>` element.

Your fragment files should go in the `_includes` directory (`/root/_includes/`) by default.

Comment: Does the included file name relative to the root of the repo or to the `_layouts` folder? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Should have mentioned, your html include files should go in the `_includes` directory located in the root directory.